# Cognos Refresh Report in Workspace

Tags: cognos

I have updated a report in Cognos and the report is out on a Workspace.
The report showing in the Workspace is not updated, I went into Widget Actions and chose Reset and the report came up as expected, with the new information.
I closed out the Workspace and went back into it but the report still showed data prior to the update.

I read in the User Guide that an icon would appear to the Workspace owner indicating that a new version of the report is available with an action available to get the new version. Well I am not the workspace owner. Report version is 'Live'.

So the question is: how can I get it so that this report indicates the changes going forward? (If the workspace owner gets the new version will it be updated going forward?)

Thank you

Comment: Also how would I go about finding out who the workspace owner is?

Comment: Another thing that worked is to access the workspace, locating the widget/report that was updated. Next right click it and select Widget Actions --> Reset. When a message comes up asking you if you want to reset the widget click 'Yes'. Lastly (and here is the crux of this solution) SAVE the workspace. Once you do this the widget will be updated going forward until the next change to the source report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way to not only find the owner but change the owner in the event that the current owner is no longer present.

Login to Cognos
Go to the report/object
Set properties
On the general tab the owner is displayed

If you have high enough permissions (including Set Policy) a link will exist to 'Make me the owner'

Thank you